# How do I fix my anaconda prompt and stop opening up gpython.exe?

Tags: deep-learning, anaconda

Whenever I open my anaconda prompt, it shows this
[image]

When I enter conda, it opens another command prompt as shown here
[image]

I have tried reinstalled anaconda but after a while, it goes back to this problem. I have added all anaconda environments to my user path but I’m still getting the same problem. How do I get past this?

Comment: " I have added all anaconda environments to my user path" -> don't do this. it completely messes up your set up and completely goes against the way environments are supposed to work, i.e. separate entities that can be activated and deactivated

Comment: Same situation here. Tried every possible way. Uninstall and install the anaconda more than 2 times. Also tried with mini-anaconda and sublime same situation. @kk_jonas did you find the solution

Comment: no , i couldn’t find the solution so i’m using google collab and kaggle kernels now .

Answer (score 0):

Go to this directory "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" and delete any python file(can be ground.exe with python icon or other) running there, it worked for me. Might work for you too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to fix it with Malwarebytes. There was a virus renaming and hiding files then taking their place. The gPython.exe was the virus file being run instead of the actual anaconda file.

[Here's the Malwarebytes log of the virus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXYMr.png)